# EditForm gives "The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again" error

Tags: error, edit-form, sharepoint-designer, server

I get a "The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again" message when I attempt to Edit an item from a specific list using its EditForm. Our SharePoint is hosted via Office 365 so I cant use many of the similar questions already answered here. I used SharePoint Designer to customize the EditForm that is showing the message, but I have done that before for other forms without the error. I can edit items from the list view just fine. This error only happens in the EditForm of the Enrollment list.

Here is a step by step on how I encounter this error:

From a Training Calendar item's DispForm, we click on the "Click Here To Edit A Student's Enrollment In This Session" link. 
[image]

The javascript behind the link takes us to the EditForm of the Enrollment List. After I click the Save button, the message shows up. Like this...

[image]

Any idea as to what is going on?

Comment: I suggest you to use Fiddler to see what kind of response comes back exactly from the server. It does support capturing HTTPS traffic as well.

Comment: that's weird, that message usually appear on on-premise servers when they run low in ram o high cpu usage.
I had never seen that message on O365, but apparently this has already been reported previously in community forums of O365.

Comment: Did you try to remove your custom code in the editform and try to save? Is it working?

Comment: I got Fiddler and not too sure how to use it. I did find this in Fiddler when poking around. <Error href="/FlowCalUltimate/meta.v1/Actual/AssetState"><Message>Not an AttributeDefinition or Operation</Message></Error>. Not sure what to make of it. I also tried to remove the custom code in the editform. Maybe I will try creating a whole new editform.

Comment: I created a whole new EditForm1 and it works. I did not edit the new one so it does not have the functionality of the faulty one. So this means the error is in the old EditForm. Anyone have an idea as to what is going on? I will try to add the custom code in this new EditForm1 and see how it behaves. Will update soon.

Answer (score 1):

I know what the problem is. The link is using the edit form without an ID in the Query string. When you edit an item you must have a ID=# in the query. Thus, what I want to accomplish here is not possible without hard coding an ID.

Answer (score -1):

If the item has unique permissions, the user must have at least Read access on the site level.